# Passing an integer array to a function inserts "0"s between values

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm trying to pass an int array to a function to manipulate it in C.
However, something seems to be going wrong with the values in the array when I do so, or in accessing them.

The following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void aprint(int* arr, int n){
    int i;
    printf("calling aprint():\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){        // changing to "i < n" to "i < 2*n" gives "2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0"
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    int *arr[5] = {2, 1, 3, 5, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    printf("in main():\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    aprint(arr, n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Gives an output of

```
in main():
2, 1, 3, 5, 4,
calling aprint():
2, 0, 1, 0, 3,
```

When I would expect

```
in main():
2, 1, 3, 5, 4,
calling aprint():
2, 1, 3, 5, 4,
```

Extending the range of the print loop in `aprint()` to 2n gives the numbers in the original array interspersed with "0"s. What's going wrong, please? I am using gcc.

Comment: `int *arr[5]` is an array of pointers, not an array of integers. It should be `int arr[5]`

Comment: You're getting zeros because pointers are twice as large as integers on your system.

Comment: Didn't you get a lot of warnings when compiling this? If you did, why did you ignore them? If you didn't, it's time to adjust the command line arguments! For instance for `gcc` use at least `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`

Comment: I see, thank you!
@SupportUkraine yes (I usually run -Wall), but I had no idea what they meant (even after searching online) so I hoped that an answer here would shed light on things (which they did)

Comment: @YWH Never ignore warnings.... If you get a warning you don't understand (and can't find described on SO already), you can ask SO about the warning. Warnings is often an indication of a bug in the program so handle all warnings before running the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the warnings:

```
p.c:14:20: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    int *arr[5] = {2, 1, 3, 5, 4};
```

You will see that the type of `arr` is not correct. You declared an array of 5 pointers to `int`s but initialized it with `int`s. Change `int *arr[5]` to `int arr[5]` as it looks to be what you need/want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have used array of pointers as below:

```
*arr[5] = {2, 1, 3, 5, 4};
```

What you should use as below:

```
arr[5] = {2, 1, 3, 5, 4};
```